# How to get a value from a column in another dataframe (df2), based on ID and on a value that points to the name of the column in df2. Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So I have this df1:

```
ID    State
1      AA
2      AA
3      ZF
3      CJ
```

and df2:

```
ID    AA    ZF  CJ  etc
1     9      8  77
2     7      6   5
3     8     88   6
```

I have to create a new column in df1 bringing the values in df2 like this:

```
ID    State    Value
1      AA       9
2      AA       7
3      ZF       88
3      CJ       6
```

I've been trying for 2 hours now and I can't seem to find a way to refer to the column names on df2 based on the values of df1['State']. Even if I could think of a way to do that, the value is filtered by ID too... tricky stuff. Any help?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try something like:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 3},
                    'State': {0: 'AA', 1: 'AA',
                              2: 'ZF', 3: 'CJ'}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3},
                    'AA': {0: 9, 1: 7, 2: 8},
                    'ZF': {0: 8, 1: 6, 2: 88},
                    'CJ': {0: 77, 1: 5, 2: 6}})

merged = df1.merge(
    df2.set_index('ID')
        .stack()
        .reset_index()
        .rename(columns={'level_1': 'State', 0: 'Value'}),
    on=['ID', 'State']
)

print(merged.to_string(index=False))
```

`merged`:

```
ID State  Value
 1    AA      9
 2    AA      7
 3    ZF     88
 3    CJ      6
```

---

Uses stack to get each value in `df2` into its own row:

```py
print(df2.set_index('ID')
        .stack()
        .reset_index()
        .rename(columns={'level_1': 'State', 0: 'Value'}))
```

Output:

```
   ID State  Value
0   1    AA      9
1   1    ZF      8
2   1    CJ     77
3   2    AA      7
4   2    ZF      6
5   2    CJ      5
6   3    AA      8
7   3    ZF     88
8   3    CJ      6
```

Then this easily merges with `df1`

Comment: It definetly worked, thank you! The only problem now is that my df1 has 4milion rows, and merged ended up with only 700 thousand, any clue why that might be?

Comment: Default merge is inner merge. So only values that appear in both dataframes would end up in `merged` you might look at a different `how`.

Comment: Oh of course, pardon my short circuited brain. May I ask why is this 'level_1' in there?

Comment: [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas-dataframe-stack) "Return[s] a reshaped DataFrame or Series having a _multi-level_ index". "level_0", in this case, is the "ID" column, and "level_1" is the "State" column, when `reset_index` is called, the name of the column becomes "level_1" by default, renaming it to "State" just simplifies the merge condition. Likewise, the new column that was created with the values is given an automatically generated name `0` and is renamed for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `loc`

```
df1['value'] = df2.set_index('ID').stack().loc[(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df1))].to_numpy()
```

or

```
idx,cols = pd.factorize(df['State'])
df2.set_index('ID').reindex(df['ID']).reindex(cols,axis=1).to_numpy()[range(len(idx)),idx]
```

Comment: Not sure if I follow how this would work without specifying the State. Tried it anyway and got :
ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!
Thank you for the answer

Comment: I edited it to use `loc` which can handle non unique indexes

Comment: although I am unsure if this will work for your real life data. Both reindex and loc worked for the sample provided.

Comment: It did not work for my job task, but it did work on my side activities so thank you for this elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to map the columns of the second DataFrame to a row in the first DataFrame, you need to first Transpose the second DataFrame, I also suggest removing the 'ID' column for ease:

```
df2.drop('ID', axis = 1, inplace = True)
df2 = df2.T
df2.columns = ['State', 'Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3']

final_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'State', how = 'left')
```

Comment: I thought of tranposing it, but the problem I see with this method is that the same state has different values depending on the ID. Wouldnt this code ignore that? Also df2 has 600 lines.. Thanks for the help